# copying sqlserver2000 database from one computer to sqlserver 2008 of another computer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-backups

i have a database named **SAHS** in my desktop having sqlserver 2000 installed i want to copy it in my laptop(64bit) having sql server 2008 ..
i tried removing a backup of it..

like this ;

```
BACKUP DATABASE SAHS
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\BACKUP\SAHSFullRM.bak' 
WITH FORMAT;
GO
```

can i copy the backup file in my laptop and use the restore statement?.. if yes please show the restore statement im getting error in this :

```
restore database SAHS 
from disk = 'C:...'
```

saying operating system error. 
is there any other simpler way to do so..pls help

Comment: Did you create a blank database on your laptop first? You might also need the `WITH MOVE` option of the `RESTORE` command if your directories are different on your laptop.

Comment: i tried this too , it showed me operating system error and restoring cancelled abnormally.i tried restoring with **with move** too

Comment: ok sir .. actually im a newbie so quite unaware .. but thnq for making me understand the reputation rate concept .. :)

Comment: Have you tried using the restore methods in the SSMS UI? It would be easier if we had more information regarding the error message (if there is a number, etc). But as John Dewey pointed out the most common error associated with a restore is that of permissions on the folder where the backup file is being stored. IF your full error says: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied)' then John is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it myself .Open sqlserver management studio ,from the object explorer expand database column, right click any databse , select **task** --> **restore** --> **database** or **Files or Filegroups** , restore dialog box opes , write the new name of yor database in **To Database** , select location and type it in **From Device** option , select the checkbox , and click on **OK** ..
ITS DONE .. this is a new feature in sqlserver 2008 ..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the target server has access to the folder containing the bak file. And on the target server you can try running the Restore Database wizard from SSMS.